# t-sql user defined function to replace text with a lookup from a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014

UDF are not my cup of tea sadly and I'm using SQL2014

I want to use a UDF to replace text in a string by looking up the value to be replaced from a table with the replacement value in the same row in another column I managed to find this example below but that only removes the last row for the lookup table

Here is the one that is not quite right so I'm looking for one that will work please

```
USE [WebProductDataBase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Ufn_ReplaceSeller]
(
 @Value   varchar(max)
)
RETURNS  varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

declare @Return   varchar(max)

SELECT @return = Replace(@Value, LookupValue, ReplaceValue) FROM dbo.Dim_Seller

RETURN @return
End
```

Here is an extract from my lookup table (currently the value we need to replaceValue is set to blank as that's is what we need to remove the LookupValue from the string) See example of the string below with the result needed

```
SellerID    Name            LookupValue      ReplaceValue   SellerUrl   DataID
AW2485      ActivInstinct   ActivInstinct                               1
AW6342      All Outdoor     All Outdoor                                 2
AW3023      Ambr            Amb                                         3
AW3469      Amp Bos         Amp Bos                                     4
AW988       Beau Expert     Beau Expert                                 5
AW222       Sloggi          Sloggi                                      6 
AW333       Ladies          Ladies                                      7

Source Row Field    Result Needed
Ladies 1 Pack Sloggi Invisible Supreme Midi Briefs
Ladies 1 Pack Sloggi Invisible Supreme Midi Briefs
Ladies 1 Pack Sloggi EverNew Cotton Midi Briefs
Ladies 1 Pack Sloggi EverNew Cotton Midi Briefs
```

The Better Option would be a multi replace function as I will need one to lookup and remove multiple values going forward
Source Row Field    Result Needed
Ladies 1 Pack Sloggi Invisible Supreme Midi Briefs  Invisible Supreme Briefs
Ladies 2 Packs Sloggi EverNew Cotton Midi Briefs    EverNew Cotton Briefs

```
So the LookupValue would be     ReplaceValue
Sloggi                          Blank
Ladies                          Blank
Midi                            Blank
Packs                           Blank
Pack                            The rest below would also be blank for now
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   
0
```

By The A. This has spaces in front and at the end

This list will be quite long by the end of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will work:

```
BEGIN
    declare @Return varchar(max);

    SET @Return = @Value;

    SELECT @return = Replace(@return, LookupValue, ReplaceValue)
    FROM dbo.Dim_Seller;

    RETURN @return;
End;
```

I'm not a big fan of using variables in functions like this (modifying the variable and setting it at the same time).  This version should work, however, and is much simpler to code than a `while` loop using the table or a cursor and should be faster than a recursive CTE.